# How to transform the regions in which a piecewise function are defined?

Tags: regions, code-request, piecewise, inequalities

I have a function `f[x,y,z]` that has a piecewise definition, i.e., its values depends on the ranges of the arguments. Now suppose I have a coordinate transformation `{X[x,y,z],Y[x,y,z],Z[x,y,z]}`. As a function of the new variables the ranges will be different. How can I use Mathematica to give me the ranges in the new variables?

For example, let

```
f[x_,y_,z_] := a HeavisideTheta[x] + b HeavisideTheta[-x].
```

Now consider

```
X[x_,y_,z_] = z(x-y)
Y[x_,y_,z_] = z(x+y)
Z[x_,y_,z_] = z
```

Clearly in the new variables the ranges will be different. Indeed the inverse is $(x,y,z)=\left(\frac{X+Y}{2Z},\frac{Y-X}{2Z},Z\right)$ and it is clear that $x<0$ and $x>0$ now depend on whether $Y<X$, $Y>X$ and $Z<0$ and $Z>0$.

I want a systematic way of obtaining these regions in the new coordinates using Mathematica.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `UnitSpet` instead of `HeavisideTheta` and `PiecewiseExpand` which converts nested piecewise functions into a single piecewise function:

```
f[x_, y_, z_] := a UnitStep[x] + b UnitStep[-x] // PiecewiseExpand
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
f[x, y, z] /. {x -> (x + y)/(2 z), y -> (y - x)/(2 z), z -> z} // FullSimplify
```

or

```
f[(x + y)/(2 z), (y - x)/(2 z), z] // FullSimplify
```

---

[image]

You can see the new conditions in the definition: `(x + y) z > 0`...